# В чем запустить код?

Tags: c++

Всем привет, есть код C++, в чем его запустить, чтобы работал без проблем?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace System;

int main()
{
    unsigned long Size = 256;
    char *Buffer = new char[Size];
    GetUserName(Buffer, &Size); //получаем имя пользователя
    cout << Buffer << "\n"; //выводим его

    //Выводим типы дисков
    char buf[26];
    GetLogicalDriveStringsA(sizeof(buf), buf);
    char *DRF[] = { "Unknown", "Invalid path",
        "Removable", "Fixed", "Network drive", "CD-ROM", "RAM disk" };
    for (char *s = buf; *s; s += strlen(s) + 1)
        cout << s << " " << DRF[GetDriveTypeA(s)] << endl;

    //специальные папки windows
    Console::WriteLine();
    Console::WriteLine("GetFolderPath: {0}", Environment::GetFolderPath(Environment::SpecialFolder::System));
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Здесь смесь нативного и управляемого кода. Поэтому пробуйте Visual Studio.

Comment: очень похоже на c++/cli - это такой непонятный с++ от Майкрософта, который работает на .NET.

Answer (score 3):

Вы используете конструкции `.NET` поэтому вам надо запускать и отлаживать ваш код в Майкрософт Visual Studio как консольное приложение с поддержкой `CLR`

Comment: Запустил как Вы и написали, выдает ошибку Ошибка 1 error C2664: GetUserNameW: невозможно преобразовать параметр 1 из "char *" в "LPWSTR" c:\Users\Server\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Testing_C++\Testing_C++\Testing_C++.cpp 17 1 Testing_C++

Comment: @Dragwor Данная функция использует так называемые wide строки, а вы используете  обычные "узкие" строки. Отсюда и ошибка, так как аргумент функции не совместим с определением ее параметра.

Comment: Ок, а как это исправить, просто с подобными функциями я никогда не сталкивался?

Comment: @Dragwor Вам надо что-то одно выбрать: либо управляемый код, либо неуправляемый код. Конкретно этой ошибки, то надо использовать тип wchar_t вместо char.

Comment: поменял данную строку 'wchar_t *Buffer = new wchar_t[Size];' Появились 3 ошибки: **error LNK2028: ёё√ыър эр эхЁрчЁх°хээє■ ыхъёхьє (0A000426) "extern "C" int __stdcall GetUserNameW(wchar_t *,unsigned long *)" (?GetUserNameW@@$$J18YGHPA_WPAK@Z) т ЇєэъЎшш "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)** ======= **error LNK2019: ёё√ыър эр эхЁрчЁх°хээ√щ тэх°эшщ ёшьтюы "extern "C" int __stdcall GetUserNameW(wchar_t *,unsigned long *)" (?GetUserNameW@@$$J18YGHPA_WPAK@Z) т ЇєэъЎшш "int __cdecl main(void)" (?main@@$$HYAHXZ)**======  **error LNK1120: эхЁрчЁх°хээ√ї тэх°эшї ¤ыхьхэЄют: 2**

Answer (score 1):

1. В Visual Studio.
2. ```
   char *Buffer = new char[Size];
   ```

   Эту память надо освобождать через delete:

   ```
   delete[] Buffer;
   ```
3. Зачем такая каша из разных технологий?

Comment: Здесь такая каша действительно не нужна. Но в целом c++/cli как раз задумывался для упрощенной связки нативного c++ кода с управляемым .Net

Comment: Код не мой, мне дали, это программа для экзамена, но никто не знал в чем раньше его запускали